# Bind a class in one Vue component's template to a Window event emitted from another Vue component

Tags: vue.js

To be able to emit events and listen for these events in all instances I do this:

```
window.Event = new Vue();
```

Then inside a Vue component's template I emit the event "isSelected", like so,

```
Vue.component('artikel',{
    template: '<li style="list-style-type:none;"><input @click="isSelected" type="checkbox" class="kryssruta" /><slot></slot></li>',

    methods:{
      isSelected(){
        Event.$emit('isSelected');
      }
    }

});
```

Now in another component, I listen for the event (I stripped out everything but the button):

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: `
          <button class="button" :class="{grey:toggle}">Lägg till</button>
  `,

  data(){
    return{
      toggle: true
    }
  },

  created(){
    Event.$on('isSelected', function() {
      alert('works!');
      this.toggle = false;
    })
  },
```

Inside the created() function I listen for the event, and I can confirm that it is recieved with the alert function.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to use the event to toggle the button's class. Anyone?

EDITED:
Thanks to the comment from skirtle, it now works with an arrow function, like so:

```
  created(){
Event.$on('isSelected', () =>  this.toggle=!this.toggle);
  },
```

But as I understand it arrow functions are not supported by IE, so I would also like to figure out how to use the suggestion about .bind(this) from Joshua Minkler, but I can't get that to work... I get "toggle is not defined".

```
  created(){
    Event.$on('isSelected', function() {
      toggle.bind(this) = true;
    })
```

Comment: You've got a scoping problem with `this` due to the extra function. If you use an arrow function instead for your event listener it should work fine.

Comment: You can also fix the scoping problem by calling [.bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) on your function.

Comment: This looks like a use case for an Event Bus: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: skirtle: Thanks, that worked! Upvote.

Comment: Joshua Minkler: could you please look at my updated question? I don't get .bind(this) to work... did I misunderstand you?